# Ember js QUnit Test : visit with parameters

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-qunit

I have blow setup

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
ember.js:14463 DEBUG: Ember      : 1.7.0
ember.js:14463 DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.9
ember.js:14463 DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
ember.js:14463 DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.1
ember.js:14463 DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

I am trying to test page http://localhost:9000/#/orange/c07f234e-8f19-4c99-c6f1-208a7d6661bd

Here is my test

```
test("/orange", function() {
  visit("/#/orange/ ?"); <------ what should i do here
  // helper waiting the application is idle before running the callback
  andThen(function() {
    //todo
  });
});
```

Is there anyways to pass parameter in the visit method of qunit